# Business Intelligence for VS 2012 on WS2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql, visual-studio

I have Windows `Server 2008 R2 Enterprise`, `x64` with Visual Studio 2012 Pro.
I want install [Business Intelligence](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=36843), but can't do it:
[image]
What I do wrong?

**Solution: use [it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36843)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're using the 32bit installer on Windows 2008 R2 which is 64 bit. More information [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1da9135d-3f8a-4318-a629-a69f07a8b019/edition-wow64-platform-error-on-widnows-7?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade).

Comment: Thnks for asnwer, but why on download page write what it support Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64) if no?

Comment: It supports 32bit for Windows 7 and Windows 8 32bit under Supported Operating System: https://i.imgur.com/DmFDJgz.png

Answer (score 1):

You're right that this is supported on a 64-bit system. However, you probably have the 64-bit version of SQL Server installed. According to [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jenss/2013/03/06/finally-the-familyunited-sql-server-bi-project-templates-now-available-in-visual-studio-2012/) (and several others that I saw), you have to choose the "new instance" option during install instead of adding features to an existing SQL Server installation. That should get you around the platform incompatibility issue.